# AEM - Users not synched with User Synchronization using Sling Distribution

Tags: aem, sling

I do not see new user info (or updates to user profiles) being synched to/from Publish-Author.

When I create a new user on Publish, I can see that there is a “SimpleDistributionAgent” on Author.. but I cannot find the user in Author(searched entire crx).

I did all the osgi configs as detailed here:
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/security/security/sync.html

I do not see any error in the log…

**Publish error.log**

```
 09.03.2017 14:27:41.711 *INFO* [127.0.0.1 [1489091261702] POST /libs/sling/distribution/services/exporters/socialpubsync-reverse HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.distribution.servlet.DistributionPackageExporterServlet  Processed distribution export request in 8 ms: : fetched 1
 09.03.2017 14:27:41.841 *INFO* [127.0.0.1 [1489091261793] POST /libs/sling/distribution/services/exporters/socialpubsync-reverse HTTP/1.1]
 org.apache.sling.distribution.agent.impl.SimpleDistributionAgent [agent][socialpubsync-reverse] exported package distrpackage_1489091245609_7459cd18-91d9-404c-bb08-a296dd5d4aa4 with info DistributionPackageInfo{ request.type=ADD, 
 request.paths=[/home/users/C/C3Pz6GaEbUDD5-rdYr7Z/profile]} from queue default by exporter socialpubsync-reverse
```

**Author error.log**

```
 09.03.2017 14:27:41.740 *INFO* [sling-default-19-scheduledEventTriggerorg.apache.sling.distribution.agent.impl.SimpleDistributionAgent$AgentBasedRequestHandler@7971f913] 
 org.apache.jackrabbit.vault.packaging.impl.JcrPackageDefinitionImpl unwrapping package sling/distribution:socialpubsync-vlt_1489091245573_674d4c01-853e-4c53-8828-31f63dda85d2:0.0.1
 09.03.2017 14:27:41.801 *INFO* [sling-threadpool-70fe0a04-9496-4992-803d-ea75f39514ae-(apache-sling-job-thread-pool)-3-org_apache_sling_distribution_queue_socialpubsync_endpoint0(org/apache/sling/distribution/queue/socialpubsync/endpoint0)] 
 org.apache.sling.distribution.agent.impl.SimpleDistributionAgent [agent][socialpubsync] [endpoint0] PACKAGE-DELIVERED DSTRQ45: 
 ADD paths=[/home/users/C/C3Pz6GaEbUDD5-rdYr7Z/profile], importTime=6ms, execTime=879ms, size=5058B
```

**No errors in Author and Publish Sync diagnostics**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User synchronization will not create users on Author. The sync is only between Publishers.

> As of AEM 6.1, when user synchronization is enabled, user data is automatically synchronized across the publish instances in the farm and are not created on author.

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/security/security/sync.html

With the above setup, i started up 2 publish instances (4503, 4504) and when i create or update any user (or profile), the data is synched between both Publish instances.

Comment: Also, just to add author is used just as a medium to sync users across publish instances. Author doesn't contain actual users. Did you had requirements to sync users to author instances from publish by any chance?